# PHP Working With Numbers

Tags: php, numbers

I have two values coming from the database that are for payments, these numbers need to be rounded to the correct format, the way I'm doing it is not working.

```
Number1: 150000 -> This should be £150.00
Number1: 3000 -> This should be £30.00
```

Using

```
<?="£" . number_format($packagePrice,2);?>
```

Returns

```
Total Price: £18,000.00 
It should be £180.00
```

Thanks

Comment: Just divide them by 100?

Comment: Why on earth are you storing 150000 if you really mean 150.00?  That just makes no sense.

Comment: @PatrickQ It maybe makes sense because storing integers could be more easier than floating point numbers.

Comment: @PatrickQ ... could be a payment gateway thing, IIRC SmartPay require that you send the order value through in the minor currency units (e.g. pence or cents) - possibly because Yen is just Yen.

Comment: @CD001 and Syscall,  That very well may be, but the relation between 150000 and 150.00 doesn't hold for that.

Comment: @PatrickQ ... lol, good point :D Unless the OP added one too many zeroes on 150000; 3000 => 30 works.

Comment: @CD001 That's possible, but I prefer taking the posting as written instead of trying to play mind-reader.  OP has had ample opportunity to fix any mistakes, but has remained silent.

Comment: @PatrickQ - oh agreed, I just misread the number of zeroes in 150000.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does it right as you past it an integer and number_format just adds following zeroes.

A quick solution would be to divide by 100 or 1000 depending on how you save to DB

```
<?="£" . number_format($packagePrice/100,2);?>
```

Comment: it's more hacking than a real solution

Comment: @LeoR. how is this hacking? The numbers the OP fetches from the DB have 2 additional 0's, so dividing them by 100 is the only logical thing to do.

Comment: Did you try your method ? with 150000 this return £1,500.00 instead of £150,000

Comment: Well, obviously the OP made a typo. Otherwise his question clearly doesn't make sense.

Comment: OP changed the question , first it was 2 additional 0's , now there are 2 and 3 :) .

Answer (score -4):

Try this :

```
$number = 150000;

// Default english notation
$english_format_number = "£".number_format($number);
print($english_format_number);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please [read the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) if only 1 argument is passed, it separated the thousands. That's it.

Comment: i readed this doc, and my example answer correctly to his problem :) next time think 30 seconds before answering unnecessarily

Comment: This answer is wrong. He wants `150000` to equal `£150.00`. Yours equals `£150,000`

Comment: It will not do , this will give `150,000` and not `150,00` as requested

Comment: the goal is to get a correct currency format from an integer not the number of 0 after the comma

Comment: @LeoR. Wrong. Look at what OP said. `Number1: 150000 -> This should be £150.00`

Your answer does not do that. You're changing what OP wants.

Comment: [Be nice](//stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Be usefull and i will be nice..